# How to increase display timeout of the java.awt.SystemTray?

Tags: java, awt, trayicon

I am using the below code to bring a system tray on the screen through my application. But I am not able to find how to increase its timeout for display. Can anyone pls help?

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

//If the icon is a file
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
//Alternative (if the icon is on the classpath):
//Image image = Toolkit.getToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");
//Let the system resizes the image if needed
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
//Set tooltip text for the tray icon
trayIcon.setToolTip("System tray icon demo");
tray.add(trayIcon);

trayIcon.displayMessage("Applicaiton ver 4", "Launching Application... \nPlease wait for a while !!!", MessageType.INFO);
```